# Adobe Flash App based Linux Distro

Tags: linux, flash

What would be the best way to create a small Linux image that just runs a single Flash SWF on startup (full screen)?  Are there distros catered to something like this, or is my best bet manually slimming down an image and then adding something into one of the startup scripts?

Also, what's the best way to run an SWF outside of a browser? gnash? swfdec? other?

Answer (score 1):

Pick a distribution that's small and has X11 available.  Do not use a window manager and specify the software you want to execute within `.xinitrc`.  There are typically system-wide scripts that impact the starting of X11 as well if you want to move it out of the rc file but they are often distribution specific.

If you want recommendations on client software, you might have better luck on Superuser.